# Codeigniter 2.1, php 5.3, Oracle & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, codeigniter

I am developing a reporting web app for a client of mine. Their accounting software runs off of an oracle db.

While i know there is a possibility of creating a connection to oracle via codeigniter. Im not sure of how to go about it. Can someone provide a list of differences between connecting via mysql and oracle.. or even just an example.

The framework will use a mysql db to store app specific information (credentials, visitor statistics, email information, logs, etc). However all accounting information is pulled from the oracle server.

Comment: Doctrine works very well with Oracle. You can integrate Doctrine into Codeigniter rather easily. Make sure you install the pdo_oci php extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more helpful to give it a shot yourself and then come back with any specific issues you run into, but here's a snippet of `/config/database.php` from a CodeIgniter app that connects to an Oracle database:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "[Database Name]";
$db['default']['username'] = "[User/Schema]";
$db['default']['password'] = "**********";
$db['default']['database'] = "";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oci8";
```

Answer (score 3):

I had issues until I have put everything in UPPERCASE, also when doing sql queries in the Model, etc. put Table Names in uppercase! (I use Oracle XE)